# Laravel Inertia Vue почему так тормозит?

Tags: laravel-9, inertia

Laravel 9, Inertia, PHP 8,1 VUE
На проде без авторизации все летает. После авторизации пользователя запросы по 25-30 секунд. Те же самые запросы, которые без аутентификации летают. В локальной среде все ОК. Что так может тормозить после авторизации на проде? Может с инерцией как-то связано? Как с таким сталкивался?

АПДЕЙТ

Да, после авторизации на продакшене отрабатывает запрос к БД 30 секунд, который в локальной среде 50милисек. Запросы идентичны, бд идентичны - и там и там только тестовые данные, создаются миграциями и сидингом автоматом. Как в разных средах такая разница в выполнении одинаковых запросов может быть? Очень это странно. Сам запрос к сожалению не могу выложить. Что это в принципе может быть?